# How can I make a method that prints out the status of each field for inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    int weight;
    String examine;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight){
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void examine(){
        System.out.println("item: " + getName() + "\n" + "weight: " + getWeight() + "\n");
    }
```

So, these are my code. The examine() method will print out the name and the weight variable. However, if another class inherits from this class, how can I make the method print out other properties as well if it is inherited.
For example, if I make make a defense class that has a field called "defense", and the defense class inherits from the Item class, how can I make the examine() print out the properties of the "defense" field as well.

Comment: Hint: Override `examine()`.

Comment: In the `examine()` of `Defense`, after printing out Defense's properties, call `super.examine()` so that it's parent implementation is called and so on.

Comment: Don't forget to extend the Item class, otherwise super calls on Object as its superclass (I believe)

Comment: What is the definition of *status* of a field? I know what the *value* is, but what is the *status*?

Comment: Let me paraphrase what I meant by my status. So, I am trying to make a new class that inherits from the Item class. I want the examine() inherited from the super class print out the value of the field as well. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your defense class you would have a method called examine() and it would override the super class method. If you want it to also print the super class examine try this.

```
//In a separate class
public class Defense extends Item{
    //Defense methods

    public void examine(){
        super.examine(); //This will call the super method examine(), which you declared in the Item class.
        //Print whatever you want from the defense class
}
}
```

> Edit 1:

For more information on inheritance, please refer to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm for a simple, yet understandable tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit like this:

```
public class GoodItem extends Item {

    int defense;

    public int getDefense() {
        return defense;
    }

    public void setDefense(int defense) {
        this.defense = defense;
    }
    public void examine(){
        System.out.println("item: " + getName() + "\n" + "weight: " + getWeight() + "\n" + getDefense());
    }
}
```

Calling examine() on GoodItem object will return a specialized output - unique to this derived class.